# Which mySQLi image data type is used for images

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I have a database which needs to house the name of images for each entry. I plan to manually store the images in a separate folder, so there's no uploading needed. What I'd like to know is **what type** should I use for this field in my table. (Is it BLOB?) All I plan to do is display it in its own div with something like

```
<img src="imageFolder/<?=$row['imageFileName']?>">
```

...which I think is correct.

Comment: so why are you both storing the images AND wanting to insert a BLOB? Kind of overkill if you ask me and twice the coding work.

Comment: if you're not planning to store as a (binary) blob but merely a path (and name) to that image, then no, it's not BLOB but a type that accepts strings, varchar for example is one. Consult http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-types.html for more.

Comment: marked as duplicate by Fred -ii- php 35 mins ago

This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.__________

Similar questions have been asked, but variables excluded them from being appropriate to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you want to store in the DB is the filename or the the URL to the file right?  If so, just use a standard Varchar.  If its just the filename, you can probably safely make it a length of 80, but if its a full URL, it may be safer to go with 200 or even 255.  (Unless you know the URL format exactly, and can set a lower length.)  (Just make sure its long enough to not break in the future. :)  )

Comment: I only posted a comment which is similar to what you wrote, because I have a funny *Spidey sense* feeling that the question wouldn't be marked as closed. The OP has a pretty bad track record in regards to that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fair enough.

Comment: Thanks SilicaGel. As stated in my question, that's all I needed.